# Why "Google Play Services for AR" is incompatible with MI A1?

Tags: compatibility, arcore, xiaomi, mi

Why "Google Play Services for AR" is incompatible with MI A1?

Is there any way to install Google Play Services for AR on a Xiaomi MI a1 device?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ARCore need specific certification process to be certificated.

Mi A1 is not only supported list.
Please check whether your device is supported.

https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices